# What attributes can I use in ngView to display the template for the current route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and one of the assignments reads like this:

> Now, add a new `div` tag to our `index.html` with an attribute directive that 
>   will include the rendered template for the current route.

That is, I need to put something inside the following `div`, which will render the correct (according to routes) template.

```
<div class="main-wrapper">

</div>
```

In all examples that I could find, this task is solved by putting `<ng-view/>` into the HTML code.

But this answer is wrong.

How else can I implement it (render the template, which corresponds to the current route) ?

Comment: `<div ng-view>`. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: @NewDev Thanks. Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngView` directive can be used both as an element:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

and as an attribute

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Answer (score 0):

`<ng-view/>` is required from the ngRoute module. Templates may be resolved using  `$routeProvider` as

```
angular.module('ngViewExample', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/Book/:bookId', {
        templateUrl: 'book.html',
        controller: 'BookCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'book'
      })
      .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
        templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
        controller: 'ChapterCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'chapter'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

If you want to manipulate your templates from the controller you could also use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). You still need to resolve your route inside your controller before fetching the proper template.